# Powershell - Replacing a string with a variable ending with a dollar sign

Tags: regex, string, powershell, replace

I'm a bit lost with this one. For whatever reason the replace function in powershell doesn't play well with variables ending with a $ sign.

Command:

```
$var='A#$A#$'
$line=('$var='+"'"+"'")
$line -replace '^.+$',('$line='+"'"+$var+"'")
```

Expected output:

```
$line='A#$A#$'
```

Actual output:

```
$line='A#$A#
```

Comment: There is something else going on here - this code has a trailing $ and works fine: `'$test$' -replace '^.+$', 'TEST$'`

Comment: It doesn't look like just the trailing $ that's the problem. It's that the trailing $ is combining with the ' to form the special $' regex variable. $' represents everything after the match. Since your regex matches the whole string, there's nothing after the match and so the $' gets replaced by nothing. I'm trying a few different ways of escaping to prevent this behavior but haven't found the right way yet.

Comment: Better question - what are you trying to do? The lines look like, frankly, you have no clue what you are doing.

Comment: And you are not replacing with something ending with `$`. You are replacing with something ending in `$'` which has special meaning

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're getting hit with a regex substitution that you don't want. The regex special variable `$'` represents everything after your match. Since your regex matches the entire string, `$'` is effectively empty. During the replace operation, the .Net regex engine sees `$'` in your expected output and substitutes in that empty string.

One way to avoid this is to replace all instances of `$` in your `$var` string with `$$`:

```
$line -replace '^.+$',('$line='+"'"+($var.Replace('$','$$'))+"'")
```

You can see more information about regex substitution in .Net here:

**[Substitutions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewy2t5e0%28v=vs.90%29)**

Comment: That's not a solution because as soon as you change $var to something else like $var='A#$A#$$' you are stuck with the same issue. $var is a dynamic variable defined by a user's input. It's not statically set.

Comment: As manojlds asked in his comment, what are you trying to do? I thought you were using an abstract example to illustrate a problem. Replacing $ with $$ will avoid that problem, whether you're working with user input or a string you define yourself. With a bit more info about your goals, we may be able to come up with a better solution.

Comment: I'm creating an installer script that sets the correct variables within another powershell script. The script being edited will have a line like $password='' that needs to be set to work, so the installer script will ask the user for the correct value of that variable and edit the corresponding line in the destination script.

Comment: No, the approach is correct.  All of the replacement special sequences begin with `$`, so you just need to escape any literal `$` with `$$`.

Comment: However the implementation is incorrect - the key piece should be `$var -replace '\$','$$$$'` or better `$var.Replace('$', '$$')`.  How could you forget to escape the `$` in this answer? :)

Comment: Ha @latkin you caught me, I noticed that late and just made the edit when I saw your comment. How awful to make an escaping error while answering a question about escaping problems! I used the -replace syntax initially but I actually think your suggestion about .Replace() makes it much clearer. I'm going to update and use that instead, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a band-aid of sorts by replacing $ with a special character and then reverting it back after the change. Preferably you would choose a character that doesn't have a key on your keyboard. For me I chose "¤".

```
$var='A#$A#$'
$var=$var -replace '\$','¤'
$line=("`$var=''")
$line -replace '^.+$',("`$line='$var'") -replace '¤','$'
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand the purpose of your posted lines, it seems to me that it would just make more sense to do `$line='$line='''+$var+"'"`, BUT if you insist on your way, just do **two** replace calls, like this:

`$line -replace '^.+$',('$line=''LOL''') -replace 'LOL',$var`